# How to run commands sequentially via Neovim's jobstart in Lua?

Tags: lua, editor, neovim

Given a series of commands to run, where each subsequent command depends on the completion of the previous, how can one execute these commands sequentially in Lua via Neovim's [`job`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/job_control.html) control functionality?

As an example, when compiling `.tex` files, one often needs to run [`pdflatex`](https://www.tug.org/texlive/) twice, followed by [`biber`](https://biblatex-biber.sourceforge.net/), and then a final run of `pdflatex` in order to resolve all references/hyperlinks within the document.

When attempting to do this with multiple `jobstart` calls as shown below, the calls are made in separate spawned jobs, which means that (in effect) they are happening "simultaneously", leading to compilation errors:

```lua
local pdflatex_cmd = "pdflatex file.tex"
local biber_cmd = "biber file.tex"

vim.fn.jobstart(pdflatex_cmd)
vim.fn.jobstart(pdflatex_cmd)
vim.fn.jobstart(biber_cmd)
vim.fn.jobstart(pdflatex_cmd)
```

Attempts to use `job_running = vim.fn.jobwait({job_id}, 0)[0] == -1` in between each `vim.fn.jobstart()` call with the corresponding job ID to iteratively check the status of a job (i.e. wait) fails to work.

Is there a way to ensure that the previous command issued with `jobstart` has completed, either by using `vim.fn.jobwait()` or by some other means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of attempting to run multiple commands separately, one can concatenate them with `;`  as a separator and pass the result to `jobstart`. For example:

```lua
local pdflatex_cmd = "pdflatex file.tex"
local biber_cmd = "biber file.tex"
local multiple_cmds = pdflatex_cmd .. "; " .. pdflatex_cmd .. "; " .. biber_cmd .. "; " .. pdflatex_cmd

vim.fn.jobstart(multiple_cmds)
```

On Linux, separating commands with `;` (e.g. `cmd1; cmd2; cmd3`) allows one to run each command after the previous regardless of whether the previous command executed successfully, or with errors. For completeness:

- If the subsequent command must only run when the previous command executed successfully, then `&&` can be used. For example, when issuing `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3`, if `cmd1` fails, `cmd2` won't be executed. Using this option would be ideal for compiling .`tex` documents as one doesn't need subsequent commands to run if the previous failed.
- If the subsequent command must only run when the previous command executes with errors, then `||` can be used. For example, when issuing `cmd1 || cmd2 || cmd3`, if `cmd1` fails, `cmd2` will be executed.